# Handling error messages with files run automatically with a batch script

Tags: batch-file, error-handling, batch-processing, errorlevel

I'm using a batch script to automatically run some simulations and record data. 
However, because this is for the purposes of testing, I routinely get error messages that pop up from the batch script because there was a bug in the simulation software. I'd like to add in a couple of different things into the script, both of which I'm extremely fuzzy on the implementation, hence my question.

1st, I'd like to put in a script that will cause an entry to become null when an error message pops up.

I have a loop that looks like this

```
for /f "delims=_" %%J IN ('forfiles /p "%%F" /m *.ext/c "cmd /c echo @path"')  DO (
    set start=!time!
    start "PROGRAM"  /D "c:\Path\to\the\PROGRAM" /Wait program -r  %%J  

    rem This loop uses a regular expression to find the database name from the .ext file
    rem and sets it to a variable.
    for /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%a in  ('findstr "<Name>ABCDir" "%%~fJ"') do set name=%%a

set end=!time!

rem The following two loops convert start time and end time to centiseconds.
rem The time variable will be converted to minutes inside a sql query so that floats are possible.
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("!start!") do (
        set /a "start=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
    )       

for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("!end!") do (
        set /a "end=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
    )

rem Calculate the elapsed time by subtracting values
set /A elapsed=end-start

sqlcmd -S SERVER -d DATABASE -v Var1 = "!name!" Var2 = "%variable2%" Var3 = !elapsed! Var4 = %variable4% -i "\\path\to\the\query\Insert.sql"
)
```

So I'd like so that everytime an error message pops up, the script starts running the next file and changes the `!elapsed!` variable to `null`.

But I would like to also add in a script that will echo what the errorlevel is that pops up. I've seen one method of doing this is like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET ERRORLEV=1
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 SET ERRORLEV=2
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 SET ERRORLEV=3
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 SET ERRORLEV=4
   •
   •
   •
IF ERRORLEVEL 254 SET ERRORLEV=254
IF ERRORLEVEL 255 SET ERRORLEV=255
ECHO ERRORLEVEL = %ERRORLEV%
```

but there seems like there should be a more efficient way to do this like with a loop that counts up errorlevel i set errorlev = i where i=0 and goes to n.

I really appreciate any insight you guys can offer.

Comment: would this work placed inside the loop?
`set /A elapsed=end-start`
`echo Elapsed Time: !elapsed!`
`IF !ERRORLEVEL! GTR 0 echo Error Level !ERRORLEVEL! Occurred.`
`IF !ERRORLEVEL! GTR 0 set elapsed=NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, if all you want to do is conditional execution based on the zero or non-zero exit code of "PROGRAM", use `&&` and `||` to designate code blocks for success or fail like this:

```
for /f "delims=_" %%J IN ('forfiles /p "%%F" /m *.ext/c "cmd /c echo @path"')  DO (
    set start=!time!
    start "PROGRAM"  /D "c:\Path\to\the\PROGRAM" /Wait program -r  %%J && (

        rem program exited status 0 (success)

        rem This loop uses a regular expression to find the database name from the .ext file
        rem and sets it to a variable.
        for /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%a in  ('findstr "<Name>ABCDir" "%%~fJ"') do set name=%%a

        set end=!time!

        rem The following two loops convert start time and end time to centiseconds.
        rem The time variable will be converted to minutes inside a sql query so that floats are possible.
        for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("!start!") do (
            set /a "start=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
        )       

        for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("!end!") do (
            set /a "end=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
        )

        rem Calculate the elapsed time by subtracting values
        set /A elapsed=end-start

        sqlcmd -S SERVER -d DATABASE -v Var1 = "!name!" Var2 = "%variable2%" Var3 = !elapsed! Var4 = %variable4% -i "\\path\to\the\query\Insert.sql"

    ) || (

        rem Program exited status non-zero (fail)
        set "elapsed="
        rem Continue looping to next result of forfiles

    )
)
```

See [this page](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.ConditionalExecution) for more on this sort of conditional execution.

Regarding echoing the errorlevel, it's already in `%ERRORLEVEL%`.  You don't have to use a series of `if ERRORLEVEL` statements to set it.  Try this on the command-line:

```
cmd /c exit /b 5
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

It should echo 5.

One other note, although I'm not sure you still need it knowing what you know now, `if ERRORLEVEL N` checks if `%ERRORLEVEL%` is greater than or equal to N.  So `if ERRORLEVEL 5` would return true if `%ERRORLEVEL%` is 8.  For this reason, series of `if ERRORLEVEL` commands are usually written in descending order.

```
if ERRORLEVEL 3 (
    do stuff
) else if ERRORLEVEL 2 (
    do something else
) else etc...
```

Comment: Okay, after reading up on conditional execution, I'm convinced this is the best way, but I'm just not following the logic. 

Can you explain logically why you put the `&&` and `||` specifically where you did?

Comment: oh and just to make sure I follow the second part, I should just need to add an `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` to my script because the errorlevel is always stored in that variable?

I'm using enabledelayedexpansion in my script for the variables set in the loop, should I use `!ERRORLEVEL!` instead of `%ERRORLEVEL%`?

Comment: It evaluates to `expression && success || fail`.  I think more specifically, `(expression && (success code block)) || (fail code block)`, which is why "fail" doesn't come before "success".  Otherwise, `&& success` would always be true.  This syntax is commonly used to check whether a string exists in another string, like `ping -n 1 host | find "TTL=" >NUL && success || fail`.  In that example, `find` sets errorlevel 0 if found, 1 if not found.  Re: second part, yes, just add `echo Program exited with status code %ERRORLEVEL%` wherever you want it echoed.

Comment: I apologize for not responding, other matters at work have kept me away from this task for a few days. I'm not sure the conditional execution is what I'm looking for. I don't want the program to either execute or not execute based on whether the last iteration ran successfully or not. I want to have a line so that if an error code shows up, then it changes the value of a variable to null.

Comment: So just leave out the `&& ( code block )` part and do `start program etc. || set "elapsed="`.  You can later test whether `start program` was unsuccessful with `if not defined elapsed` if you wish.  If you prefer, you can `start program etc` on one line, then the next line `if errorlevel 1 set "elapsed="`.  It's 6 of one, half a dozen of the other, really.  Both styles perform identical actions.

Comment: I can't get this to work in my code. I have the code set up so that it looks like this `&& (file loop) || (error loop)` but everytime I execute the code, it crashes. I implemented it just as you did in your answer.

Comment: Your pseudocode is fine.  Try disabling the `@echo off` and see if you can see which command causes the crash.  If that doesn't help, update your question with your updated code, or post a new question.

Comment: Are the comments relevant? I was looking over the page you linked explaining it and it seems to be the case.

Comment: Are what comments relevant where?  You mean the `rem` statements in the script in my answer?  Most of those are yours.  Are you asking whether they affect the evaluation of the script?  No, I don't believe so.  I think you should post a new question.

Comment: I was referring to the comments you added

Comment: You mean `rem program exited status 0 (success)` and `rem Program exited status non-zero (fail)`?  They're only there to illustrate the purpose of `&&` and `||`.  You can delete those and all other `rem` lines if you like, and it shouldn't affect the running of the script.